# How is the kernel process kswapd started step by step?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

I understand the impacts and functions of the kernel process`kswapd`.

As the output of `ps -elf | grep swapd`, I found `kswapd` is started by `kthreadd`. But how is it started step by step? Where's the extract related source code?

Here is the output of `ps -elf | grep swapd`:

```
$ ps -elf | head -n 1; sudo ps -elf | grep -i kswapd
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
1 S root        46     2  0  80   0 -     0 kswapd 11:42 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]
```

You see, the PID of the kernel process `kthreadd` is 2:

```
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
1 S root         2     0  0  80   0 -     0 kthrea  6/2       00:00:00 [kthreadd]
```

In addition, I can't find a binary program with the same name throughout the rootfs. For details, see below:

```
$ cat /proc/46/cmdline
#outputs nothing
sudo find / -iname kswapd 2>/dev/null
#outputs nothing
```

Comment: You're not asking how kswapd is "started" by a program, are you? In other words, are you asking how kswapd is initialized or are you asking how kswapd gets woken up by an arbitrary program?

Comment: You can't find executables because those are kernel threads, and kernel threads only exist in the kernel code itself, there's no separate executable. `kthreadd` is also a kernel thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think [mm/vmscan.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/vmscan.c) has all or most of the answers you're looking for.

If you're asking how kswapd is initialized, the file contains [kswapd_init()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/vmscan.c#L4072).

If you're asking how kswapd is woken up by a process that needs more memory, the file contains [wakeup_kswapd()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/vmscan.c#L3951).

You can use a combination of grep, printk, and dump_stack() commands to step through the instructions executed before and aaft